# How to put values above bars in barchart in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, bar-chart

How to put values above bars in barchart in Matlab?

Note, that there can be several bars per position of unknown width, so you can't just do `text`

```
y1 = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5];
y2 = [5; 4; 3; 2; 1];
bar([y1, y2]);
text(0.75:1:(length(y1)-0.25), y1, num2str(y1,'%.0f'), 'VerticalAlignment', 'bottom', 'HorizontalAlignment', 'center');
text(1.0:1:(length(y2)+0.0), y2, num2str(y2,'%.0f'), 'VerticalAlignment', 'bottom', 'HorizontalAlignment', 'center');
```

[image]

I can try some position guessing, but would like to avoid it.

Comment: Please explain 'unknown width'. AFAIK `bar()` can give you the left and right bin edges of each bin as output.

Answer (score 3):

You can know the locations of the bars with

```
b=bar([y1, y2]);
```

`b.XData` gives you the location, `b.BarWidth` its width, `b.BarLayout` will tell you if there are more than one in the same location (to adjust for width) and so on. [Read more about the available properties](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.bar-properties.html).

With this information you should be able to just put `text` wherever you want.